# highlight html.erb and js.erb in vscode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code

I have problem to use html.erb files in vscode, I tried to format my document and i did it, but the document lose the style just like in the picture:
https://ibb.co/KLqjfcV

settings.json I have:

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html.erb": "html"
  },
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "html.erb": "html"
  }
```

I appreciate any comments!

Comment: Please copy paste the code instead of posting an image URL.

Comment: if I copy the code you will not be able to see the style of the code

Answer (score 3):

#### Update 2023

After trying out multiple extensions:

- [erb](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CraigMaslowski.erb): used to work fine, but it's been deprecated since 2018.
- [Rails](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bung87.rails): too much more than I need, for instance, code snippets, go-to definition, etc.
- [Ruby LSP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shopify.ruby-lsp): great extension by Shopify but doesn't handle ERB syntax highlighting.

The one that worked the best for me was [Ruby Syntax Highlighting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SarahRidge.vscode-ruby-syntax) by Sarah Ridge

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install some package as well as set some settings up as mentioned in this [post](https://medium.com/@PaulWritesCode/ruby-on-rails-with-visual-studio-code-bc5681a2c098)